# ASP.NET MVC Add and use user tables in a custom database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm very (**very**) new to ASP.NET, I chose MVC due to having some experience with php's Symfony.
I have an external SQL database that I (hopefully) have linked it to the project using this command:

```
<!-- web.config -->
 <add name="1AKrygowskiConnectionString"
       connectionString="server=127.x.y.z,xyz; database=1AKrygowski; User ID=1AKrygowski; Password=foobar; Catalog=1AKrygowski;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now I would like the sites Identity to generate the required user tables in the database and use them.

Now some smart articles on google told me that if I properly adress the aplicationDbContext it would set EntityFramework to generate said user tables in my db and use them from now on.

So I did:

```
//IdentityModels.cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("1AKrygowskiConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this did not work and I have ran out of sources that would explain the proper way to do it to me.

Could anyone here please help out a fellow noob in achieving something probably extremely simple.
Simple words would be great.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use EntityFramework migrations to create SQL commands to create the tables. A step by step guide is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I've done everything in the tutorial yet no tables have been created in my db ._.

Comment: You did migrations? In NuGet Package Manager Console, do this:

enable-migrations

THEN 

add-migration TestMigration

THEN

update-database -verbose